# Send email from Mac OS X via perl script

Tags: macos, perl

I am trying to send email using a Perl script from my Mac, for which I have installed
MIME::Lite module. I am using a basic script to test:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use MIME::Lite;

$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
                 From     =>"abc\@gmail.com",
                 To       =>"xyz\@gmail.com",
                 Subject  =>"Demo",
                 Data     =>"Sent :-):-)"
                 );
$msg->send();
```

I have already set up my email account in my macbook. 
Please guide me if I need something else to check for as i am unable to send the email.

Comment: Add authentication if you want to send the mail via your Email provider, just consult the module documentation

Answer (score 1):

Gone are the days when you could just use a system call out to the command line:

```
mail boss@megacorp.net -s "I QUIT!" < body_of_message.txt
```

But if you install and configure mutt to talk to your mail server, you can do something pretty close:

```
mutt -s "I QUIT" boss@megacorp.net < body_of_message.txt
```

The hardest bit is configuring mutt, and that's not too bad.  There are a ton of docs and howtos out there, like [Mutt Configuration Doc](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-3.html) ...or just google for "mutt configure" and the type of mail server that you're using; gmail, exchange, etc.

From there, in perl, you would just:

```
system("/path/to/mutt", "-s", "I QUIT", "boss\@megacorp.net", ...)
   or die "Could not send Email";
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this module but I note the docs for it say

> MIME::Lite is not recommended by its current maintainer. There are a
>   number of alternatives, like Email::MIME or MIME::Entity and
>   Email::Sender, which you should probably use instead. MIME::Lite
>   continues to accrue weird bug reports, and it is not receiving a large
>   amount of refactoring due to the availability of better alternatives.
>   Please consider using something else.
>   [http://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite](http://metacpan.org/pod/MIME%3a%3aLite)

Having said that, you may need to do something like

> Specify default send method:
>
> ```
>  MIME::Lite->send('smtp','some.host',Debug=>0);
>  MIME::Lite->send('smtp','some.host', AuthUser=>$user, AuthPass=>$pass);
> ```